# Trying to run development server on HTTPS but certifcate not found

Tags: django, https

I am trying to run the development using HTTPS to have it have a secure connection. The issue I run into is `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: '/tmp\\cert.crt'`

I have done:

`pip install django-extensions Werkzeug pyOpenSSL`

Than I have set my settings in my settings.py file to this:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True 

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True 

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

and I have also added this line here:

```
    'django_extensions'
```

to my installed Apps

and when I run this line `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert`

I get the error

Comment: Is the certificate file called `cert.crt` or just `cert`?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, it seemed like there it was not createing a certifcate, so I ran `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt` which solved the issue